# Amenities I do not use but am being required to pay for

Tags: landlord

Can a landlord force tenants to pay for a service they did not request/enroll in? I am specifically asking about the $12/month package service that the landlord now says is not optional. Also, they require all tenants to have a renter's insurance policy (which I have), but now they are charging me $10/month to use their renter insurance. Do I have to use their insurance? Do I have to pay for a package service if I don't want the service?

Comment: The main beneficiary of a renter's insurance is mostly the landlord.  Your personal property is usually covered up to a very small amount.  You can ask your landlord if they no longer require you to get an outside insurance.  In which case, you should also ask the landlord for a proof of coverage.

Comment: In what city/county/country?

Comment: First and foremost: what does your lease say about the package service and renter's insurance?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether the lease requires it. If the lease requires you to have renter's insurance, you have to have renter's insurance. If it requires you to have a specific company's renter's insurance, you have to have the specific company's renter's insurance. If you don't do that, you have violated the terms of the lease and can typically be evicted. If you comply with the terms of the lease by having *some* renter's insurance and they still want you to have a specific brand of insurance, you have not violated the terms of the lease, and you cannot be evicted  for such. They cannot "bill you" just because they want to change the terms of the lease -- that requires your agreement, or they can unilaterally change the lease terms at the end of the current period. The same goes for package service (I don't even understand what a monthly package service charge would mean).

Comment: I reckon a monthly package service charge is a monthly charge for the service of receiving packages, holding them if the tenant is away, and distributing them to the tenant.